# Redundant voting meta tags

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Currently there are various meta tags for voting:

- [voting](/questions/tagged/voting)× 8
- [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes)× 4
- [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close)× 3
- [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes)× 3
- [votes](/questions/tagged/votes)× 3
- [downvoting](/questions/tagged/downvoting)× 2

There seems to be no reason to have so many different tags for voting. How can the variation be reduced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now retagged as follows:

- [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) to [voting](/questions/tagged/voting)
- [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) to [downvoting](/questions/tagged/downvoting)
- [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) to [voting](/questions/tagged/voting)

Comment: I think any tag that has less than 20 questions can just be manually retagged... We just have to do it with some interval.

Comment: @jokerdino Makes sense as long as the risk of re-creation of the tags is low. Do you agree with the pattern?

Comment: I am fine with your proposal. It makes sense (to me, at least).